# Why union_all is not working properly after changing encoding in R?

Tags: r

I have been running the same code for more than one year. On my PC some of the functions that I am using are not working like union_all(), whereas on other PC everything is ok.

I reinstall R. I did something with the encoding because I got other problem before so I can't find why union_all() is not working properly. When I reinstalled R everything was OK, but after changing the encoding this problem appeared.

I got the following error:

**Error in union_all():**

**! 'x'and 'y' are not compatible.**

**x Different number of columns: 9 vs.2.**

Then, I get other errors of changing the name of the column when doing left_join.

Comment: Which package is `union_all` from?

Comment: Did you look at the data? A different number of columns from what you expect might mean the data isn't being read in correctly.

Comment: @thelatemail I think from dplyr.

Comment: @Axeman yes, I checked the data. From other PC with other version of R everything is OK.

Comment: It's difficult to help without a reproducible example, but presumably one of the data.frames has 2 columns and the other 9 columns, while on your other computer that isn't the case? Or do you have different versions of `dplyr` installed on those computers perhaps?

Comment: I found that the packages dplyr and fuzzyjoin are conflicting given the recent update of dplyr package. Thank you all!